# Orthonormal basis for the set of polynomials at most degree $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle \colon P_n \times P_n \to \mathbb{R}, \langle p, q\rangle = a_nb_n + \dots+a_1b_1+a_0b_0$ where $P_n$ is the set of all polynomials at most degree $n$ and $p(x) = a_nx^n + \dots +a_1x+a_0,q(x) = b_nx^n+\dots+b_1x+b_0$. Show that for every $j \in \mathbb{N}$ the basis $(p_0, \dots,p_n)$  defined by $p_j : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^j$ is a orthonormal basis in the inner product space defined by $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle \colon P_n \times P_n$.

It seems that I want to show that $(x^0, x^1,\dots,x^n)$ is an orthonomal basis in $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle \colon P_n \times P_n$. I would need to show that $$\langle p_j, p_i\rangle = 0 \text{ for all $j\ne i$} \\ \|p_j\| = 1 \text{ for all $j\in \{1, \dots, n\}$}$$

The first condition seems trivial since the polynomials $(x^0, x^1,\dots,x^n)$ doesn't have any coefficients and $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ was defined to be the sum of the coefficients of the two input vectors. The second condition confuses me a bit if $\|p_j\| = \sqrt{(x^j)^2} = x^j$ then how can I be sure that this evaluates to $1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^{i}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_kx^{k}$ where $a_k=0$ if $ k \neq i$ and $a_i=1$. Once you realize this it follows immediately that $ \langle p_i, p_j \rangle =0$ for $i \neq j$ and  $\|p_i\|=1$  for all $i$. [In the sum defining the inner product of $p_i$ with itself  one term is $1$ and all other terms are $0$].